# Qual Expressão Regular para tratrar uma URL

Tags: javascript

Bom, Estou perguntando é porque não sei, mas estou tentando...

## Dúvida

```
http://www.meusite.com.br/busca.html?nome=louvor+a+Deus
```

Onde: `?nome=louvor+a+Deus`

> Deve-se remover ou melhor substituir com o *método* `replace();` os símbolos **por espaços**, são eles:

```
? = +
```

Tenho a tabela `RegeX` para consulta em mãos, mas sou um tanto leigo ainda sobre o assunto.

Comment: Isso é um exercício ou tem algum objetivo prático? Digo, substituir `+` por espaços não é tratar uma URL. Me parece que você quer acessar um parâmetro da URL, então a pergunta seria: "como acessar o valor de um parâmetro de URL que está codificado?" Além disso, apenas tratar espaços não é suficiente. Experimente colocar caracteres especiais nessa busca e veja o que acontece.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nesse caso não estamos, verificando uma URL completa, apenas o que foi solicitado, se fosse uma URL seria bem mais complexa, até mesmo para se fazer a pergunta...

***Tenta assim patrão :***

```js
var str = 'http://www.meusite.com.br/busca.html?nome=louvor+a+Deus'
str = str.replace(/\?|=|\+/g,' ')
alert(str)
```

Se curtir, se adapta...

Seguindo a sugestão do mestre @Randrade, vou dar uma explicada, no regex:

As barras(slash) "/"no começo e no fim "/" delimitam a expressão.

As barras invertidas (backslash) "\" servem para escapar caracteres especias (?,+), pois todos eles tem uma função na regex, mas como queremos usá-los de forma literal tem de escapar com uma "\" backslash.

As barras verticais "|", representam ,"ou"...

E o "g" no final é uma flag, faz coincidir a mesma ocorrência várias vezes, como no caso do "+", ele só tá declarado uma vez.

[Aqui ensina umas mãnhas, Aurélio.net](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/metacaracteres.html)