# Ler valores da URL em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso ler todos os valores de uma URL (abaixo) em Javascript, pegando tanto o nome e o valor para armazenar em uma base de dados.

```
cadastro.php?codigo=4355&nome=Renan&email=renan@teste.com&celular=66992541453&40=on&11=on
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134065/qual-express%C3%A3o-regular-para-tratrar-uma-url/134078#134078

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar algo como essa função abaixo, e então usar as variáveis no final do código.

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

var mobile = getUrlParameter('mobile');
var index = getUrlParameter('index');
var table = getUrlParameter('table');
```

Espero que funcione.

Comment: Lembrando que necessito que não apenas imprima o valor e sim o nome também.

Comment: Você está falando de algo como "email=renan@teste.com" retornar "email: renan@teste.com"? Neste caso você teria que adicionar algo como var mobile = "variavelVindaURL " + getUrlParameter('mobile');

Pegou?